# how to have a unique session id in a rails 3.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to write a rails 3.1 app in which one of the views will be popping messages off of an MQ server.

I would like to have the app generate a unique id with each session so that I can use that ID as the channel name in the MQ exchange.

the idea is I want to have the app kick off some sort of backend process that will use the MQ server as a transport mechanism to get its log output sent to the browser.  when the backend app starts I would like to create a channel based on this unique id such that other sessions would not be popping messages off of the queue that were not intended for them.

I guess what I need is a way to generate a unique id per session and a reliable way to pass it around from view to view.

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using something like [Juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/), or using it as an example?

Answer (score 1):

I might not have thought this through properly but, how about the session id?

Comment: that was my hope actually.  except for some reason beyond my comprehension I can't seem to access it.  here is a sample view template {<%
# encoding: utf-8
%>
id<%= session[:session_id] %>
} and when rendered does not show the session id.

Comment: no love either;undefined method `session_id' for {}:Rack::Session::Abstract::SessionHash

Comment: My final stab at this - how about session.id?

Answer (score 1):

in your controller action:

```
def myaction
  @sessid = request.session[:session_id]
end
```

in your view:

```
{<% # encoding: utf-8 %> id<%= @sessid %> }
```

hth.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead

```
@sessid = request.session_options[:id]
```